# when leave richtextbox all text color changed to the first character color

Tags: c#, winforms

On my C# WinForm project when I leave richtextbox and enter another component all text in richtextbox color changed to the first character color.

Comment: Would you like to show us some code so we can figure whats wrong with that?

Comment: Add code to your question, not just the 2 lines. All the relevant code including what you're doing when you leave the `textbox`.

Comment: why Edit My question

Comment: this void to find word in rich text box named rtb and if rtb leaved and press another control all text color changed to the first character color if first color is red all text be red

Answer (score 0):

thank's for all 
but i was binding rich text box and fill it using data binding and after that i set acolor for some words using this void  v_srarch_WithOutTashkilAll 
after set color if i leave rich text box control to other control using mouse click then all text in rich text box recolored using the first character

Answer (score -1):

this void created to find all word in rich text box named rtb and change word color to red it's work right but if i leaved rich text box control to other control all character color be the first character color this is my proplem

public void v_srarch_WithOutTashkilAll(string word, RichTextBox rtb)
        {

```
        try
        {

            if (startSelection >= 0)
            {
                startSelection = rtb.Find(word, startSelection, rtb.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            }

            if (startSelection != -1)
            {
                char[] arr = new char[] { 'ّ', 'َ', 'ً', 'ُ', 'ٌ', 'ِ', 'ٍ', 'ْ' };


                int index = 0;
                string CurrentWord = "";
                char charForTest;
                try
                {
                    while (CurrentWord != word)
                    {
                        rtb.Select(startSelection + index, 1);
                        charForTest = Convert.ToChar(rtb.SelectedText);
                        if (arr.Contains(charForTest))
                        {
                            index++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CurrentWord += charForTest.ToString();
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    rtb.Select(startSelection, index);
                    rtb.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    startSelection += index;
                    v_srarch_WithOutTashkilAll(word, rtb);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: when are you calling v_srarch_WithOutTashkilAll? It should be on the paint event for the control in question i would imagine

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not as an answer, which it isn't!! Then delete this 'answer'!